# Python OpenCV: Why does fillPoly() only draw grey polygons, regardless of its color argument?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, drawing

I am trying to write a white mask on a black, two-dimensional NumPy array — an image with one channel — in OpenCV using Python:

```
mask = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.int8)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, np.array([[[0,0], [89, 0], [99,50], [33,96], [0,47]]], dtype=np.int32), color=255)
print(mask)
```

However, the polygon has a grey color when I print the mask:

```
[[127 127 127 ...   0   0   0]
 [127 127 127 ...   0   0   0]
 [127 127 127 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]
```

I tried a 3D NumPy array with `color=(255,255,255)`, I tried different colours, all to no avail. Why is it ignoring the `color` argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the initialization of your `mask`:

```py
mask = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.int8)
```

The value range of the [`int8` data type](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) is `-128 ... 127`, thus any value above `127` will be "truncated" to `127`.

Try your code with `color=100`, you'll get the expected output:

```py
[[100 100 100 ...   0   0   0]
 [100 100 100 ...   0   0   0]
 [100 100 100 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]
```

I guess, you wanted to use `uint8` instead of `int8`, so maybe it's just a simple typo!?

Changing your code accordingly to

```py
mask = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
```

then gives the expected result, also for `color=255`:

```py
[[255 255 255 ...   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 ...   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the datatype selection when initializing the numpy array. In your example code you are using `np.int8` , [which has a range from -128 ... 127.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html). Instead of `np.int8` you should consider using `np.uint8`, which has a range of 0 ... 255, whixh you are looking for.

`mask = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.int8)`

should be

`mask = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)`

`[[255 255 255 ...   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 ...   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]`

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was not initializing the mask with depth.

```
mask = np.zeros(shape = (MASK_WIDTH, MASK_HEIGHT), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Solved with this code

```
mask = np.zeros(shape = (MASK_WIDTH, MASK_HEIGHT, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
rcolor = list(np.random.random(size=3) * 256)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [arr], color=rcolor) 
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(mask_folder, itr + ".jpg") , cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
```